# Mimimize gstreamer CPU usage streaming filesrc as RTSP to udpsink

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I stream h264 contents as rtsp from a filesrc to a udpsink

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=./test.movie ! h264parse  ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9004
```

This pipeline works well but gives a quite high CPU load and my question is if there is any way of minimizing the CPU load, limiting the processing rate?

Feels like since there is a filesrc and udpsink there is really nothing stopping gstreamer from just working as quick as it can. A 35sec movie takes <0,5 seconds for gstreamer to stream with the given pipeline.

Comment: Are you trying to play it smoothly as a live stream, on the client end?  Or just throttle the data?  If you just want to throttle it, set the max-bitrate attribute on udpsink.  Playing it smoothly would probably be a much harder issue...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the proposal, the problem is that that is one of the few properties on GstBaseSink that is only supported in 1.0, not in 0.10. Will see if I can switch to 1.0.